# Standard way of filling webform fields with session or cookie values

Tags: webforms, cookies, 9

Is there a standard way of filling Webform (hidden) fields with session variables and cookies?

In previous versions of Webform (4.x?), I've read that some placeholders could be used for setting the default value the one in a cookie or session variable, but this functionality was apparently removed (maybe when Webform switched to use the more standard Token module?)

I'm imagining two ways of doing this, but all of them may require custom code:

- Implementing a custom component that acts like a hidden field but that gets its value from a specific cookie/session variable of choice.
- Exposing cookies & session variables as tokens, and then use default Webform default value mechanism with tokens. Ideally, I would like the form editors to be able to choose any cookie/session variable they want, so I'm not sure this can be done that way.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the point of this. You already have your own, known (server-side) data like a session value, then fill it in a hidden (user-side) form field and submit it back to the server? This sounds super-weird. Why not check for the session value in a custom SubmitHandler?

Comment: The point is to allow form editors to add and remove fields. Even if the values are set in the submit handler, the form editor should be able to choose which variables will be submitted, and the way I thought of doing this was via the form build page.

Comment: @Pere if you want the editor to be able to add and remove fields, then I'd recommend using a conditional `if($user->hasRole('administrator')){}` to display the field `$form["elements"]["example"]['#access'] = true;`. And then using Ajax hiding that field if the user clicks to remove that field.

Comment: @ArmandoSilva I am not sure I'm following. In the Webform module, editors are usually able to add and remove fields via the UI, in the build/component page of that form. This was about adding fields that are populated using cookies and session variables

Comment: Oh I see. Well if you want to build a custom element so that it autopopulates its value based on cookies and session variables, perhaps look at [WebformExampleElement](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/tree/HEAD/modules/webform_example_element)